# Remove items from Array skips certain items

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I have the following page (simple):
[image]

As you can see, at the top I have an input, then `<ul>` and finally a button to save changes. My `<ul>` is bound to a array of `items`. Once user clicks Uloz zmeny (Save Changes) I am triggering `ng-click="vm.SaveChanges()"` which looks like following:

```
    vm.SaveChanges = function () {
        angular.forEach(vm.items, function (value, key) {

            if (value.toRemove == true) {
                //remove item from the list

                var iIndex = vm.items.indexOf(value);
                vm.items.splice(iIndex, 1);
            };
        });
    };
```

where `vm` is defined as following at the beginning of my code:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("app-shopping").controller("itemsController", itemsController);

    function itemsController($http) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.items = [];.....more code after here
```

Every item under my '' has the following structure:

```
  {
    "id": 2,
    "orderId": 2,
    "text": "Item 2",
    "toRemove": true
  },
```

Finally, when user checks an item under the `<li>` I am triggering `vm.toggleCompleted()` which simply looks like this (it simply changes a boolean state of current item from true to false or vice versa):

```
    vm.toggleCompleted = function (sItem) {
        sItem.toRemove = !sItem.toRemove;
    };
```

Here comes the question: Why when I run this code it does not remove all checked items in the array? For example in this specific case (see image above) it would only remove `Item 2` and skip `Item 3`. I believe that the problem is caused by the fact that when `Item 2` is remove from the list, `Item 3` takes the index of already existing `Item 2` and therefore is skipped. Is this assumption correct? If yes, how do I need to change the code to make this run?

P.S. Edit to my code as recommended:

```
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="sItem in vm.items">
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                <input id="ListItem{{$index}}" type="checkbox" placeholder="test placeholder" ng-model="sItem.toRemove" ng-click="sItem.toRemove=!sItem.toRemove" />
                <label for="ListItem{{$index}}">{{sItem.text}}</label>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: I think your assumption is correct.  A clever way to remove all the items is to loop in reverse - start at the highest index and remove from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using toggleCompleted use below at the place of check-box input

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.toRemove" ng-click="item.toRemove=!item.toRemove" />
```

And Use your new saveChanges method .. this should work fine..

Comment: This looks fantastic! I have changed the code, but I can no longer check the item (it is always unchecked). I have added the code to my post

Comment: did you go through the plunk i had pasted in the comment .. putting it again ..http://plnkr.co/edit/6tpG8Kr4vWyRlF5ZNtxs?p=preview . .. If you could create a sample plunk for your issue it will be easy for us to help you further .. just use one static object and create.. its very simple to create if you are new to plunk..

Comment: I have created a plunk, but for unknown reason, it does not work. Anyways, the full code is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/vfWZmHLJ3oRxiMLuh5H9

Comment: Actually your `ng-app` ins't `plunker`, that's it. Also you didn't include ngRoute library.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/rg1rl9AcWpxKCcyHWVs6?p=preview   take a look at it .. its working fine now ..I have created one .

Comment: Let me know if it works fine for you .. i have shifted ng-click from input to top div ..

Comment: removed `ng-click` and it works like a charm now! Could you explain why ng-click was causing the trouble? was it double negation of the boolean (which resulted always in the same result) ?

Comment: It happens because of new scope generation .. go through few scope related articles and then you will automatically start understanding such things .. one i found helpful github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 3):

I have changed the code the following way and it is working now:

```
    vm.SaveChanges = function () {
        for (var i = vm.items.length - 1; i > -1; i--)
        {
            if (vm.items[i].toRemove == true)
            {
                vm.items.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Robert .. have a look at a plunk i had created few days back for better understanding of check-box handling in AngularJS  ..http://plnkr.co/edit/6tpG8Kr4vWyRlF5ZNtxs?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to bypass this issue, just revert your array traversal, because this way you can guarantee that no position of unchecked elements changes during deletion.

Answer (score 0):

So, you code at the end should be like that:

Template:

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="sItem in vm.items">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
        <input id="ListItem{{$index}}" type="checkbox" placeholder="test placeholder" ng-click="sItem.toRemove = !sItem.toRemove" />
        <label for="ListItem{{$index}}">{{sItem.text}}</label>
    </div>
</li>


<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="SaveChanges()"> Save</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.SaveChanges = function () {

        for (var i = $scope.vm.items.length - 1; i > -1; i--){
            if ($scope.vm.items[i].toRemove) {
                $scope.vm.items.splice(i, 1);
            };
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi Yoan, thank you for your answer. One question though - why are you trying to retrieve an index of an item when you already know it - variable ``i`` is the actual index. This does not make any sense to me